# search-bar for JSON (API), need help:)

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

i am currently stuck trying to code a search-bar for an JSON fil (linked via an API link and key). I am fairly new to coding and especially new to this field.

i currently cant get my function to work with onkeyup() maybe because its an async function? as i said im fairly new to this so idk, and I get an error for my "x.innerHTML = "" " saying "Cannot set properties of null", now i may look like an idiot here and missing something obvious but I would very much appreciate all answers:)

thanku for your time!

HTML:

```
 <div id="søk"><input id="søkefelt" onkeyup="søk()" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <ul id="listHolder"></ul>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (Event) => {
async function søk() {
    const apiKey = await fetch ("nyheter.json")
    .then ((response) => response.json());

    var data = await fetch ("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=" + apiKey[0].apikey)
    .then((response) => response.json());

    let input = document.getElementById("søkefelt").value
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.querySelector("listHolder");
    x.innerHTML = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const obj = data[i];

        if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            const elem = document.createElement("li")
            elem.innerHTML = '${obj.title} - ${author}'
            x.appendChild(elem)
        }
        
    };

        }
søk();
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` requires `#` before ids

```
querySelector("#listHolder")
```

Comment: thanks! it still says that søk(); is not a function for the onkeyup in the input... :/

Comment: Because you can only access global functions in html, but your functions isn't global because it's declare inside another function

Comment: oh... hehe, what would you recommend to do to make it a global function?

Comment: Remove `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (Event) => {`. But I would rather recommend not using html attributes to handle events

Comment: okay, thanks! it still wont work but i dont get any error messages:)